# Cards on music.google.com appear to change depth on hover, can I do this with angular material?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I notice that the "day of week music station cards" add depth (height?) as soon as you hover over them. Is there a way to make cards behave this way using Angular Material Design? please answer with demo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`md-whiteframe` class can change the depth, `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` will execute on hover, and `ng-class` can be used to set the class.

```
    <md-card  ng-mouseenter="hover = 'md-whiteframe-z3'" ng-mouseleave="hover = ''" ng-class="hover">
```

Comment: It works for **all** md-cards at the same time. Is there any way to make this working only for that card, which was hovered?

Comment: this should only work for the hard that yo're hovering over... because it applies the style to just that card